# How can I remove the first 3 duplicate values and return an array with the remaining values?

Tags: ruby

Given these arrays, how do I remove three occurrences of a value while keeping the fourth or fifth in the array?

```
[1,5,1,1,1] # => [1,5]
[3,3,3,2,3] # => [3,2]
[3,4,5,3,3] # => [4,5]
[1,1,1,1,1] # => [1,1]
[1,2,2,4,5] # => [1,2,2,4,5]
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
array = [1,5,1,1,1]
top3 = array.select { |x| array.count(x) >= 3 }[0..2]
last2 = array - top3
```

This strategy (and similar) only seem to work when there are three duplicates but not four or five. Are there elegant solutions to this problem?

UPDATE: Thank you for your amazing answers. As a beginning rubyist I learned a lot just from analyzing each response. My question came from a Ruby Koan challenge for a dice program. Here's my complete solution implemented with Abdo's suggestion. I'm sure there are more efficient ways to implement the program :)

```
def score(dice)
  a,b,c,d,e = dice
  array = [a,b,c,d,e]
  total = 0
  triples = array.select {|x| array.count(x) >= 3}[0..2]
  singles = array.group_by{|i| i}.values.map{ |a|
       a.length > 2 ? a[0, a.length - 3] : a
      }.inject([], :+)

# Calculate values for triples
# 1 * 3 = 1000pts
# 2 * 3 = 200pts
# 3 * 3 = 300pts
# 4 * 3 = 400pts
# 5 * 3 = 500pts
# 6 * 3 = 600pts
case triples[0]
  when 1 then total += triples[0]*1000
  when (2..6) then total += triples[0]*100
end

# Calculate values for singles:
# 1s = 100pts each
# 5s = 50pts each
singles.include? (1) ? singles.select {|x| x == 1 }.each {|x| total += x*100 } : total
singles.include? (5) ? singles.select {|x| x == 5 }.each {|x| total += x*10 } : total

return total
end

puts score([5,1,1, 5, 6]) # 300 points
puts score([]) # 0 points
puts score([1,1,1,5,1]) # 1150 points
puts score([2,3,4,6,2]) # 0 points
puts score([3,4,5,3,3]) # 350 points
puts score([1,5,1,2,4]) # 250 points
```

Comment: Do you care about the order of the elements in the output array?

Comment: How come the duplicate 2 didn't get removed in your last example?  Could you state the problem more exactly?

Comment: @DavidGrayson the order of the output does not matter. The duplicate in the last example did not get removed because the method should detect duplicates of three or more and return the remaining two values.

Comment: You should try to phrase this more clearly.  I think I would say: for every element e, if it is in the input 0-2 times it is in the output the same number of times.  If it is in the input three or more times, it is in the output 3 fewer times than the input.

Answer (score 2):

```
array = [1,5,1,1,1]
occurrence = {}

array.select do|a|
  if(array.count(a) > 3)
    occurrence[a] ||= []
    occurrence[a] << a
    occurrence[a].count > 3
  else
    true
  end
end
```

PS: This solution preserves the order of the elements in the original array

Comment: Nice solution, Vimsha.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a faster solution when the size of the array is large:
(I avoid using count because it would loop through the array in an inner loop)

```
arr.inject({}) { 
  |h, i| h[i] ||= 0; h[i] += 1; h 
}.collect_concat {|k,v| [k] * (v > 2 ? v - 3 : v) }
```

Here's the fruity comparison to the other working solutions:

```
arr = 1000.times.collect { rand(100) }.shuffle

require 'fruity'

compare do
  vimsha { 
    occurrence = {}; 
    arr.select do|a|
      if(arr.count(a) > 3)
        occurrence[a] ||= []
        occurrence[a] << a
        occurrence[a].count > 3
      else
       true
      end
    end
  }

  caryswoveland {
    arr.uniq.reduce([]) {|a,e| a + [e]*((cnt=arr.count(e)) > 2 ? cnt-3 : cnt)}
  }

  aruprakshit {
    num_to_del = arr.find { |e| arr.count(e) >= 3 }
    if !num_to_del.nil?
     3.times do
      ind = arr.index { |e| e == num_to_del }
      arr.delete_at(ind)
     end
    end 
    arr
  }
  # edited as suggested by @CarySwoveland
  abdo {
    arr.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}) {|i,h| h[i] += 1
    }.collect_concat { |k,v| [k] * (v > 2 ? v - 3 : v) }
  }

  broisatse { 
      arr.group_by{|i| i}.values.map{ |a| 
       a.length > 2 ? a[0, a.length - 3] : a 
      }.inject([], :+)  
  }
end
```

Here's the comparison result:

```
Running each test 64 times. Test will take about 48 seconds.
broisatse is faster than abdo by 30.000000000000004% ± 10.0% 
abdo is faster than aruprakshit by 4x ± 1.0 (results differ: ...)
aruprakshit is similar to caryswoveland (results differ: ...)
caryswoveland is similar to vimsha (results differ: ...)
```

Note: I took @aruprakshit's code outside the method so we don't waste time in the method call itself.

When the array's size is increased further:

```
arr = 1000.times.collect { rand(1000) }.shuffle
```

we get:

```
abdo is faster than broisatse by 3x ± 1.0
broisatse is faster than aruprakshit by 6x ± 10.0
aruprakshit is faster than caryswoveland by 2x ± 1.0
caryswoveland is similar to vimsha
```

Comment: That's interesting, Abdo.  Good of you to have done the comparison.  A small suggesting: break longer lines (using ``\`` where necessary),  so the reader does not need to scroll horizontally.

Comment: good point .. I split the lines so we can see things more easily :-)

Comment: In your solution you could replace the first part with `arr.each_with_object({}) {|i,h| h[i] ||= 0; h[i] += 1}` to get rid of that annoying `h` at the end.  Notice that the block args are ordered differently. Alternatively, `arr.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}) {|i,h| h[i] += 1}`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, assuming order need not be preserved (which is consistent with a comment by the asker):

```
array = [1,2,4,1,2,1,2,1,1,4]

array.uniq.reduce([]) {|a,e| a + [e]*((cnt=array.count(e)) > 2 ? cnt-3 : cnt)}
  #=> [1, 1, 4, 4]
```

Comment: using `uniq` is great because it prevents `count` from iterating over the array when not needed. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
a.group_by{|i| i}.values.map{|a| a[0, a.length % 3]}.inject([], :+)
```

This will remove all triplets from the array. If you want to remove only the first triplet, then do:

```
a.group_by{|i| i}.values.map{|a| a.length > 2 ? a[0, a.length - 3] : a }.inject([], :+)
```

Note: This might mess up the order of the array:

```
[1,2,1,2,3]           #=> [1,1,2,2,3]
```

Let me know if you need to keep the order and, if so, which elements need to be removed if there are more than three, e.g. what should say: `[1,1,2,1,1,]` - `[1,2]` or `[2,1]`?

Comment: order doesn't matter in this situation.

Comment: Ah, that's action support extension. :) Answer updated

Comment: So you assumed the input array was guaranteed to be shorter than 6

Comment: There are no assumption. It will remove all triplets from the array.

Comment: Hmm, @Vimsha and I thought 4th, 5th, 6th, 7th, ... all had to be kept

Comment: It is not said in a question. I'll update the answer to cover both cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
x.group_by{|i| i }.values.select{|a| a.size >= 3 }.each{|a| c=[3,a.size].min; x.delete_if{|e| a[0]==e && (c-=1)>=0 } }
```

It will remove the first `[3,a.size].min` occurrences of `a[0]` from the input `x` where `a` is, for example, `[1,1,1,1]` for `x = [1,2,1,1,1]`

Answer (score 0):

I'd do as below :

```
def del_first_three(a)
  num_to_del = a.find { |e| a.count(e) >= 3 }
  return a if num_to_del.nil?
  3.times do
    ind = a.index { |e| e == num_to_del }
    a.delete_at(ind)
  end
  a
end

del_first_three([3,4,5,3,3]) # => [4, 5]
del_first_three([1,5,1,1,1]) # => [5, 1]
del_first_three([1,2,2,4,5]) # => [1, 2, 2, 4, 5]
```